# Ubuntu 16.04 - broken lock and shut down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, lock-screen

Last 2 days I've noticed that lock and shutdown are broken.

Lock works only with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and doesn't work on click.

Shut down after clicking locks and then from locked screen I can reboot or shut down.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the culprit - plank.

After removing it everything went back to normal.